# Value of type 'SupabaseClient' has no member 'from'

Tags: ios, swift, database, postgresql, supabase

I am trying to add data to my user_data table when the user signs up. I can get their email and password into the user table but cannot seem to get data into any other table.

The bug I am receiving here is:
Value of type 'SupabaseClient' has no member 'from'

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Supabase

class SignUpViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let supabaseURLString = JohnStamos
    let supabaseKeyString = BobSeger
    let client: SupabaseClient

    init() {
        client = SupabaseClient(supabaseURL: URL(string: supabaseURLString)!, supabaseKey: supabaseKeyString)
    }

    func signUp(email: String, password: String, userData: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        Task {
            do {
                let signUpResponse = try await client.auth.signUp(email: email, password: password)
                if let newUserId = signUpResponse.user?.id {
                    let insertData: [String: Any] = [
                        "user_id": newUserId,
                        "display_name": userData["display_name"]!,
                        "date_of_birth": userData["date_of_birth"]!,
                        "gender": userData["gender"]!,
                        "fitness_goal": userData["fitness_goal"]!
                    ]
                    let insertResponse = try await client.from("user_data").insert(insertData).execute()
                    if let error = insertResponse.error {
                        throw error
                    }
                }
                completion(nil)
            } catch {
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactored

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Supabase

struct UserData: Encodable, Decodable {
    let user_id: Int
    let age: Int
    let gender: String
    let height: Double
    let weight: Double
    let fitness_goal: String
}

class SignUpViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let supabaseURLString = "your-supabase-url"
    let supabaseKeyString = "your-supabase-key"
    let client: SupabaseClient

    init() {
        client = SupabaseClient(supabaseURL: URL(string: supabaseURLString)!, supabaseKey: supabaseKeyString)
    }

    func signUp(email: String, password: String, userData: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        Task {
            do {
                let signUpResponse = try await client.auth.signUp(email: email, password: password)
                if let newUserId = signUpResponse.user?.id {
                    let insertData = UserData(
                        user_id: newUserId.hashValue,
                        age: userData["age"] as! Int,
                        gender: userData["gender"] as! String,
                        height: userData["height"] as! Double,
                        weight: userData["weight"] as! Double,
                        fitness_goal: userData["fitness_goal"] as! String
                    )
                    let query = client.database
                        .from("user_data")
                        .insert(values: insertData,
                                returning: .representation) // you will need to add this to return the added data
                        .select(columns: "id") // specify which column names to be returned. Leave it empty for all columns
                        .single() // specify you want to return a single value.

                    let response: [UserData] = try await query.execute().value
                    print("### Returned: \(response)")
                }
                completion(nil)
            } catch {
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```